# Vim Javacomplete Plugin JDK Error

Tags: vim

I have an error while opening .java files. JDK Path is written in "PATH".
Thanks in advance-----> The screenshot is here(https://i.stack.imgur.com/420Mp.jpg)

Comment: Do you have the right vim version that the error is asking for?

Comment: I downloaded vim from the official website

Comment: That doesn't tell me much. The message in your screenshot mentions a specific version requirement.

Comment: Where else can I download the newest version of vim?)

Comment: Dude. What version do you have?

Comment: The error also mentions a required version of the JDK; do you have that installed?

Comment: I installed new version of vim, that error disappeared but as for JDK not.